# Calling a Magento event Observer AFTER payment capture

Tags: php, magento

Im trying to call an Observer after the order has been created, and AFTER payment has been captured.
So far I've tried;
checkout_submit_all_after, 
sales_order_payment_place_end, 
sales_order_place_after,
sales_order_payment_pay, 
sales_order_payment_capture, 
sales_order_payment_transaction_save_after

Just to name the main ones.
I've also logged all Event Dispaches inside dispatchEvent() but found nothing that stands out and is only fired when i need it.
the issue i'm having is that the status of the order is always ether 'Payment Pending' or something that predated this; meaning that i don't know whether the order will fail or succeed.

My aim, is to fire a function only on successful orders.
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after much more testing i found the following Observer to do the trick;

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

This returns just the order id, so;

```
$order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

and you see that the order status is 'processing' and the payment is aproved (or not).

Answer (score 3):

1 ) here is custom config.xml for call observer file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>            
            <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customFunction</method>
                    </Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                </observers>
            </checkout_submit_all_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

2 ) create observer.php file inside your module/Model directory and paste this code

```
<?php
  class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
         //here you can add your custom code

    }        

}
```

please try this.. sure it will help you !

Comment: Thanks for contributing but as i said in my question, i'd tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried all event but didn't get success. Then I moved to override Mage OnePageController and called my custom function. Below is the code to override onestep checkout.

app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml

```
<Namespace_Checkout>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
</Namespace_Checkout>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Checkout\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
  <modules>
     <Namespace_Checkout>            
        <version>0.1.0</version>        
     </Namespace_Checkout>    
  </modules>        
    <frontend>        
        <routers>            
            <checkout>                
                <args>                    
                    <modules>                        
                        <Namespace_Checkout before="Mage_OneStepCheckout">Namespace_Checkout</Namespace_Checkout>                    
                    </modules>                
                </args>            
            </checkout>        
        </routers>    
    </frontend>     
</config>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class Namespace_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController{
    public function successAction(){
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $this->customFunction(); // Custom function to call

        $session->clear();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    function customFunction(){
        // This function is calling before clearing order session
        //Here you can put all your custom code 
    }
}
?>
```

In the above controller, I have added `customFunction()` wher you can put your custom code.

Hope it will help you!