# Interceptor after payment - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I need to crete an Interceptor **after payment aprovation**.

I currently use the class

```
Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
```

With function

```
afterSave
```

But not resolve my problem, because I need an event that fires after payment approval and not every time I change the order status.

Comment: You might try: checkout_submit_all_after or sales_model_service_quote_submit_success

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at creating an observer instead:
[Calling a Magento event Observer AFTER payment capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393729/calling-a-magento-event-observer-after-payment-capture)

How to create observer in magento:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html